# In Rails, how to copy some object between independent applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeresource

We have 2 independent applications. We want to copy certain tables from one of the apps to the other. The ID of the objects being copied needs to be the same between both the apps.

Also only specific rows need to be copied between the apps.

Update: The 2 applications operate independently across different data=centers. In one of the apps, we create/update the object. Now we need to copy this exact same object across to the other app.

Comment: Do you expect to do this as a one time RDBMS activity or within your application?  If the latter, you will need to give us a bit more context.

Comment: @steveklein Thanks. It will be an ongoing activity within the application. I have updated

Comment: I would accomplish this at the database level with replication or mirroring depending on your specific requirements.  I don't believe you will want to do this in the application.